# Layout does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I'm trying to include the layout in one of my views and it's saying it doesn't exist in current context along with viewbag.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "About Me";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";}
```

I've looked at other solutions saying I need this or that in the web.config, though nothing has worked.

I'm on Mac OS and using Visual Studio for Mac Community

views/web.config:

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
     <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
         <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
         <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
     </sectionGroup>
 </configSections>
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
     <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
     <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
         <namespaces>
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
             <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
             <add namespace="GroundRoots" />
         </namespaces>
     </pages>
 </system.web.webPages.razor>
 <appSettings>
     <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.webServer>
     <handlers>
         <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
         <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
     </handlers>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

root web.config:

```
<!--
Web.config file for GroundRoots.

The settings that can be used in this file are documented at 
http://www.mono-project.com/Config_system.web and 
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5ysx397.aspx
-->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies />
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Not really sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 0):

Does the layout work on another views? Try to create a new view and check "Use a layout page" and then select your layout view file. Hope this works, it has always worked for me

Comment: it only works on the primary page. When I create a new view and use a layout page, it creates the file with the "view.bag" and "layout" bit in it. Yet they don't work as it says they don't exist in the current context.

Comment: Does your view have a controller? you always need to add an action to your view even if it's blank. For example, you have your index on controller and an index view..

Comment: I do. I have a homeController for index and my other views. Basically the real issue I'm having is that I've made a header and footer style that I want to stay throughout all views, but only the main index view is maintaining all the css. So when I try to have another view to inherit from my _layout, none of the style is appearing. I figured it's because It's not recognising that layout call?